# Shebang line with `#!/usr/bin/env command --argument` fails on Linux

Tags: linux, scripting, executable, env

I've got a simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby --verbose
# script.rb
puts "hi"
```

On my OSX box, it runs fine:

```
osx% ./script.rb
hi
```

However, on my linux box, it throws an error

```
linux% ./script.rb
/usr/bin/env: ruby --verbose: No such file or directory
```

If I run the shebang line manually, it works fine

```
linux% /usr/bin/env ruby --verbose ./script.rb
hi
```

But I can replicate the error if I pack `ruby --verbose` into a single argument to `env`

```
linux% /usr/bin/env "ruby --verbose" ./script.rb
/usr/bin/env: ruby --verbose: No such file or directory
```

So I think this is an issue with how `env` is interpreting the reset of the shebang line.  I'm using GNU coreutils 8.4 `env`:

```
linux% /usr/bin/env --version
env (GNU coreutils) 8.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Richard Mlynarik and David MacKenzie.
```

This seems really odd.  Is this a common issue with this version of `env`, or is there something else going on here that I don't know?

Comment: [relevant?](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-sh-utils/2002-04/msg00020.html)

Comment: Same here with coreutils 8.17. Weird. Reporting to Fedora, as this goes explicitly against what the manual says.

Comment: @vonbrand What did Fedora say? "We don't care."

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Looks like this is because Linux (unlike BSD) only passes a single argument to the shebang command (in this case env).

[This has been extensively discussed on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e).

Comment: see also [this page](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/) for a review of the behaviour on different Unices.

Comment: Specification fail. My god.

Comment: If by "specification fail" you mean all Unix systems should accept more than 1 argument, then I 100% agree with you :)

Comment: Not so much 'linux' as GNU.

Comment: @will not really GNU, the shebang [is parsed by Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938907/673852)

Answer (score 11):

Coreutils>=8.30:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env -S ruby --verbose
```

The `-S` or `--split-string` env option is documented in the GNU coreutils manual (see: `info '(coreutils) env invocation'` or [the online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#g_t_002dS_002f_002d_002dsplit_002dstring-usage-in-scripts)). Below is an excerpt:

> Most operating systems (e.g. GNU/Linux, BSDs) treat all text after the first space as a single argument. When using env in a script it is thus not possible to specify multiple arguments.
>
> In the following example:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env perl -T -w print "hello\n";
> ```
>
> The operating system treats `perl -T -w` as one argument (the program's name), and executing the script fails with:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/env: 'perl -T -w': No such file or directory
> ```
>
> The `-S` option instructs `env` to split the single string into multiple arguments. The following example works as expected:
>
> ```
> $ cat hello.pl
> #!/usr/bin/env -S perl -T -w print "hello\n";
>
> $ chmod a+x hello.pl $ ./hello.pl hello
> ```
>
> and is equivalent to running `perl -T -w hello.pl` on the command line prompt.

Comment: Yes. But care to explain why?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works on NixOS 22.05+ (Kernel 5.15). This is what Replit sometimes uses.

Answer (score 8):

Found this via @rampion comment:

> What happens is that the kernel processes the first two characters of
>   the file looking for #!.  If those are found then it skips all space
>   characters looking for a non-space character and extracts the
>   interpreter path which must be a real executable and not another
>   script, although linux extends that to allow recursive script
>   processing.  Having found that then it skips to the first non-space
>   character where it takes from there to the next newline character and
>   passes that as a single argument to the command.  There is no 'shell'
>   processing of quotes or other meta characters.  It is all very simple
>   and brute force.  Therefore you cannot get fancy with options there.
>   You get exactly one argument white space included and 'perl -w' is
>   what the kernel sees here and passes on.

Source: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-sh-utils/2002-04/msg00020.html