# sh -c in shebang

Tags: shell, shebang

I have a file `test` with the content

```
#!/bin/sh -c 'echo was called with $0'
```

I if i execute it it with `./test`, i would expect the OS to effectively execute

```
sh -c 'echo was called with $0' ./test
```

which to my understanding *should* result in `was called with ./test`.

However, i get the error message

```
/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -
```

**What is the reason for this Error?**

please note that i understand that there are easier ways to print the arguments, the `echo` part is a stand-in for unrelated and more complex things.

Added information: `cat -E test` gives me

```
#!/bin/sh -c 'echo was called with $0'$
$
```

Comment: @msp9011 i tested it in 2 docker containers: ubuntu:latest and alpine:latest. What is your setup?

Comment: if i replace `/bin/sh` with `/bin/echo`, it prints the rest of the shebang, since that works, i guess it's nothing general like lineendings but something sh-specific

Comment: Linux only supports one argument on the hashbang line, see [Multiple arguments in shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399690/170373), [Shebang line with `#!/usr/bin/env command --argument` fails on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63979/170373) and then there's [Sven Mascheck's page](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/) about hashbang differences in different systems, with more information you ever want to know.