# SED: How can I use -n and -f together

Tags: sed

I want to write a sed script where the echoing is off, like

```
#!/bin/sed -n -f
s/x/u/g
```

but that gives my an

```
Invalid option -- ' '
```

error.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does the script have any weird/nonprinting characters (maybe a nonbreaking space)? Try printing the script with `LC_ALL=C cat -vt scriptname` and see if it shows anything weird. If that doesn't spot a problem, add info about your OS and version of `sed`.

Comment: What do you mean by `-f` without a file name?

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63979/13792

Answer (score 5):

It's because you tried to pass more than one argument in the shebang. Compare:

- [Multiple arguments in shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399690/108618)
- [Shebang line with `#!/usr/bin/env command --argument` fails on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63979/108618)

In this particular case you can compact `-n -f` to `-nf`. In general this is not always possible. Here the script will be:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf
s/x/u/g
```

<sup>Note: It seems to me the script in its current form will print nothing because of `-n`. I assume you're going to expand it.</sup>

Comment: Note also that `-fn` would most likely _not_ work.